# how to print output in single line in oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have been using `dbms_output.put_line` to write the output in line, which is around 500000 lines with more than 500 characters.

I want the output in a single line and I had tried `dbms_output.put` .  But it does not do so as dbms_output.put has a limitation of 32000 bits. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: No production systems use DBMS_OUTPUT for any practical use. It seems you are using an entirely wrong approach. May be no PL/SQL is needed, perhaps you could do in plain SQL. But, we don't know the requirement. Post more details.

Comment: Consider using the UTL_FILE package instead.

Comment: The Logs and data is always inserted in tables and is fetched whenever required using Select statement or the data is further processed by other objects/applications depending upon the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_OUTPUT is a mechanism for displaying messages to standard output (i.e. a screen).  The nature of PL/SQL programs is they tend to be batch oriented and frequently run as background jobs, so DBMS_OUTPUT has narrow applications.  Writing out huge amounts of data is not one of them.

You haven't explained your use case, but the need to render millions of characters in a single stream of output, without carriage returns, suggests you want to write to a file.  Oracle provides a built-in for this, UTL_FILE.  We can iterate calls to UTL_FILE.PUT() to write as much data as we like to a single line in a file.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS069).

UTL_FILE has one major constraint, which is it can only write to a file on the database server.  Perhaps this is why you are trying to use DBMS_OUTPUT?

Something else?  Oracle 12c supports Streaming in PLSQL via DBMS_XMLDOM.  [Check it out](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb10pls.htm#ADXDB4898).

---

This is a pretty vague answer, because your question is pretty vague.  If you edit your question and provide actual details regarding your issue I can make my response more concrete .

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.... 
Yahhaa You are correct. I have tried to use UTL_FILE.PUT(lz_details) but fail. I had also used UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE() it is working fine but data I am getting in multiple lines instead of in single line. Please suggest if you have updation in  UTL_FILE.PUT

Comment: In what way have you failed with UTL_FILE.PUT?  It's pretty hard for me to offer when advice when you don't provide  code, don't describe what happens and don't mention an error message.